# after using The SQL Builder Class how to use order by desc or asc function?

Tags: mybatis

As we know,mybatis 3 have  the sql builder class,but i wang to know how to use 'order by xxx desc' function?

more detail as below:

https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html

i have to try to use as these code?

```java
public String selectPersonLike(final String id, final String firstName, final String lastName) {
  return new SQL() {{
    SELECT("P.ID, P.USERNAME, P.PASSWORD, P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME");
    FROM("PERSON P");
    if (id != null) {
      WHERE("P.ID like #{id}");
    }
    if (firstName != null) {
      WHERE("P.FIRST_NAME like #{firstName}");
    }
    if (lastName != null) {
      WHERE("P.LAST_NAME like #{lastName}");
    }
    ORDER_BY("P.LAST_NAME");
  }}.toString();
}
```

but we should how to use 'order by desc' function?

it will be like this if we use sql builder class?

`SELECT P.ID, P.USERNAME, P.PASSWORD, P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME FROM PERSON P ORDER BY P.LAST_NAME DESC`

Comment: You can write `ORDER_BY("P.LAST_NAME DESC")` if that is what you are asking. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: yeah,thanks for your reply,i have resolved it .

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved it .

```java
@SelectProvider(type=MockJsonDataSqlProvider.class, method="selectByExample")
    @Results({
        @Result(column="UUID", property="uuid", jdbcType=JdbcType.VARCHAR, id=true),
        @Result(column="ID", property="id", jdbcType=JdbcType.VARCHAR),
        @Result(column="CELL", property="cell", jdbcType=JdbcType.VARCHAR),
        @Result(column="NAME", property="name", jdbcType=JdbcType.VARCHAR),
        @Result(column="MEAL", property="meal", jdbcType=JdbcType.VARCHAR),
    })
    List<MockJsonData> selectByExample(MockJsonDataExample example);
```

```
public String selectByExample(MockJsonDataExample example) {
        BEGIN();
        if (example != null && example.isDistinct()) {
            SELECT_DISTINCT("UUID");
        } else {
            SELECT("UUID");
        }
        SELECT("ID");
        SELECT("CELL");
        SELECT("`NAME`");
        SELECT("`UPDATETIME`");
        FROM("T_MOCK_JSON_DATA");
        applyWhere(example, false);

        example.setOrderByClause("UPDATETIME DESC ");
        
        if (example != null && example.getOrderByClause() != null) {
            ORDER_BY(example.getOrderByClause());
        }
        return SQL();
 }
```